# symfony: format_currency() adds an space before the number

Tags: symfony1

when i do this:

```
var_dump(format_currency('1004.569'));
```

I get:

> string ' 1.004,56' (length=10)

Notice that there is a space before the 1.

Any idea?

sf 1.4.

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is where currency symbol belongs. This is because you haven't set the users default culture. If you pass "usd" as the second parameter you should get $1.004,56.

```
format_currency('1004.569', "usd")
```